# what must i add to the cmakefile.txt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I want create a node that uses a library that is installed in my pc.
To compile i typed:
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -l rt -l bcm2835

what must i add to the cmakefile.txt?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53540/what-must-i-add-to-the-cmakefile.txt/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As in any other cmake project, you'd put `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME) <NAME_OF_LIBRARY_TO_LINK>)` in your CmakeLists.txt.  There wasn't any ros-specific cmake macro for using an installed library in a node in rosbuild, and if I understand correctly, the new catkin build system does not use ANY ros-specific macros. I haven't actually used catkin yet, though.  Some useful links:

- [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_2.4.6_Docs)
- [catkin page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin)
- [rosbuild cmake API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists) (for pre-groovy distros)

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3